# Implement related search feature

Tags: algorithm

I have to implement a feature in my website, that works kind of similarly to how they do in shopping websites "**People who searched for this also searched for these.**" Which algorithm to be used for that?

Can LSI be used?

Comment: Yes, LSI can be used. Google for "netflix challenge" (which was won by _essentially_ a SVD method)

Comment: [Collaborative Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)